# How to compare the first two rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having the following tables for example purposes:

MTRL TABLE

```
|MTRL|  CODE  |
---------------
| 1  | 080109 |
| 2  | 085145 |
| 3  | 084141 |
```

MTRLINES TABLE

```
|MTRL|  PRICE  | FINDOC |
-------------------------
| 1  |  4.95   | 12345  |
| 1  |  4.50   | 23421  |
| 1  |  3.90   | 23499  |


|MTRL|  PRICE  | FINDOC |
-------------------------
| 2  |  2.95   | 45345  |
```

I am currently using those two queries and then I am storing the output to a variable. And I am doing the comparison with programming. **But instead of running two queries it would be better to run one and then take the output.**

So I want to compare the last two prices. If the last price has changed significantly or there is only one price like mtrl2 then output price1

```
SELECT 
      , SUB.PRICE
FROM (
        SELECT 
              , ML.PRICE
              , rn = row_number() over (PARTITION BY M.CODE ORDER BY FINDOC DESC)
        FROM  MTRLINES ML
              INNER JOIN MTRL M
                    ON M.MTRL = ML.MTRL  AND FINDOC IN (SELECT FINDOC FROM FINDOC WHERE SOSOURCE=1251 AND FPRMS IN (1,2)) 
              WHERE  M.SODTYPE=51 AND M.COMPANY=1 AND M.CODE=:kod_an
      ) sub
WHERE rn IN (1)
```

This is stored in variable `price1`

```
SELECT 
      , SUB.PRICE
FROM (
        SELECT 
              , ML.PRICE
              , rn = row_number() over (PARTITION BY M.CODE ORDER BY FINDOC DESC)
        FROM  MTRLINES ML
              INNER JOIN MTRL M
                    ON M.MTRL = ML.MTRL  AND FINDOC IN (SELECT FINDOC FROM FINDOC WHERE SOSOURCE=1251 AND FPRMS IN (1,2)) 
              WHERE  M.SODTYPE=51 AND M.COMPANY=1 AND M.CODE=:kod_an
      ) sub
WHERE rn IN (2)
```

This is stored in variable `price2`

I am doing programmaticaly something like (this one is vbscript):

```
If ABS(price1-price2)>0.02 Then
    Result=Price1
Else
    Result=0
End If
```

How could I achieve this with SQL only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest:

```
with prices as (
      select code,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as price_last,  
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as price_second,
             count(*) as num_prices 
      from (select ml.price, m.code,
                   row_number() over (partition by M.CODE order by FINDOC desc) as seqnum
            from MTRLINES ML inner join
                 MTRL M
                 ON M.MTRL = ML.MTRL and
                    FINDOC in (select FINDOC from FINDOC where SOSOURCE = 1251 and FPRMS in (1, 2)
                              ) 
            where M.SODTYPE = 51 and M.COMPANY = 1 and
                  M.CODE = :kod_an
           ) m
      where seqnum in (1, 2)
      group by code
     )
select (case when num_prices = 1 then price_last
             when abs(price_last - price_second) > 0.02 then price_last
             else 0
        end)
from prices;
```

Note that your code does this one code at a time.  You can drop the `M.CODE = :kod_an` and run the code on more than one code.

Comment: It is fine! Just correct the `>` with `-` Thank you!

Comment: When the mtrlines table has one row, one price for example it returns 0. It should return Price1 instead. Please have a look into it. It works when there are two rows or more...

Comment: @F.Mysir . . . One method counts the prices and explicitly includes that in the logic.

Comment: So how could we add an if statement that if mtrlines has one row return Price1? In vbscript I had 0 as return if no second line was there in second query. So I was detucting Price1-Price2 for example 3.45-0>0.02 which was true and the output was 3.45. With this query I am getting 0 in that case that mtrlines has one row

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Didn't test it in absence of sample data, but the idea is to first get both rows (rn=1 and rn=2) in a CTE. Then use `case` statements to find the `abs` value and return `0` or `PRICE` for `rn=`.

Also I am assuming that rest of your query is correct

```
;with t as (
SELECT 
      SUB.PRICE
FROM (
        SELECT 
               ML.PRICE
              , rn = row_number() over (PARTITION BY M.CODE ORDER BY FINDOC DESC)
        FROM  MTRLINES ML
              INNER JOIN MTRL M
                    ON M.MTRL = ML.MTRL  AND FINDOC IN (SELECT FINDOC FROM FINDOC WHERE SOSOURCE=1251 AND FPRMS IN (1,2)) 
              WHERE  M.SODTYPE=51 AND M.COMPANY=1 AND M.CODE=:kod_an
      ) sub
WHERE rn IN (1,2)
)
select case 
            when abs(sum(case when rn=1 
                            then price 
                            else (price * -1 ) 
                        end)
                    )
                    > 0.02  
        then (select price1 from t where rn=1) 
        else 0 end
         as result
from t
;
```

Comment: Hi, it says invalid column name `rn`